# I would like to create query that would count the number of available book with the same title

Tags: sql, group-by

I would like to create query that would count the number of available book with the same title. My table looked like this

```
Book_ID |  Book_Title |  Author | status
-----------------------------------------------------------------
122334  |  Title11111 |  allann  | available
839661  |  Title12222 |  reddd   | available
839373  |  Title11111 |  allann  | not_avail
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Book_Title |  Author | Avail_Copies | TotalCopies
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title11111 |  allann  |  1          | 2

Title12222 |  reddd   |  1          | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use subqueries to solve your task

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.book_Title,
        A.Author,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table AS A2
         WHERE A2.book_title = A.book_title
                AND A2.status = 'available') as avail_copies,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table AS A2
         WHERE A2.book_title = A.book_title') as total_copies,  
FROM Table AS A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple `SUM()` aggregate using a `CASE`:

```
Select  Book_Title, Author,
        Sum(Case When status = 'available' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Avail_Copies,
        Count(*) As TotalCopies
From    BookTable
Group By Book_Title, Author
```

[<kbd>**SQLFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef944/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Book_Title,Author,SUM(IF(status = 'available', 1, 0)) as Avail_Copies, COUNT(Book_ID) as TotalCopies FROM books GROUP BY Book_Title, Author;